# Dropping columns with high missing values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, missing-data

I have a situation where I need to drop a lot of my dataframe columns where there are high missing values. I have created a new dataframe that gives me the missing values and the ratio of missing values from my original data set.

My original data set - data_merge2 looks like this :

```
A     B      C      D
123   ABC    X      Y
123   ABC    X      Y
NaN   ABC    NaN   NaN
123   ABC    NaN   NaN
245   ABC    NaN   NaN
345   ABC    NaN   NaN
```

The count data set looks like this that gives me the missing count and ratio:

```
     missing_count   missing_ratio
  C    4               0.10
  D    4               0.66
```

The code that I used to create the count dataset looks like :

```
#Only check those columns where there are missing values as we have got a lot of columns
new_df = (data_merge2.isna()
        .sum()
        .to_frame('missing_count')
        .assign(missing_ratio = lambda x: x['missing_count']/len(data_merge2)*100)
        .loc[data_merge2.isna().any()] )
print(new_df)
```

Now I want to drop the columns from the original dataframe whose missing ratio is >50%
How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
data_merge2.loc[:,data_merge2.count().div(len(data_merge2)).ge(0.5)]
#Alternative
#df[df.columns[df.count().mul(2).gt(len(df))]]
```

or [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) using `new_df` **DataFrame**

```
data_merge2.drop(columns = new_df.index[new_df['missing_ratio'].gt(50)])
```

**Output**

```
       A    B
0  123.0  ABC
1  123.0  ABC
2    NaN  ABC
3  123.0  ABC
4  245.0  ABC
5  345.0  ABC
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding another way with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and `XOR`:

```
data_merge2[data_merge2.columns ^ new_df.query('missing_ratio>50').index]
```

Or pandas way using [`Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html)

```
data_merge2[data_merge2.columns.difference(new_df.query('missing_ratio>50').index)]
```

---

```
       A    B
0  123.0  ABC
1  123.0  ABC
2    NaN  ABC
3  123.0  ABC
4  245.0  ABC
5  345.0  ABC
```